# Fatal error: Index out of range when refreshing data on specific view

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I have the following code:

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftUIRefresh // added via SwiftPM: https://github.com/timbersoftware/SwiftUIRefresh.git

struct AView: View {
    
    @State private var aObjects = [A]()
    @State private var refreshing = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                if(aObjects.isEmpty) {
                    Text("loading")
                } else {
                    List(aObjects.indices, id: \.self) { idx in
                        NavigationLink(destination: BView(parentA: self.$aObjects[idx])) {
                            Text(self.aObjects[idx].name)
                        }
                    }.pullToRefresh(isShowing: self.$refreshing) {
                        API.getAs() { newAObjects in
                            self.aObjects = newAObjects
                            self.refreshing = false
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle("All", displayMode: .large)
            
        }.onAppear() {
            if(self.aObjects.isEmpty) {
                API.getAs() { newAObjects in
                    self.aObjects = newAObjects
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct BView: View {
    
    @Binding var parentA : A
    
    @State private var refreshing = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if(parentA.bs.isEmpty) {
                Text("loading")
            } else {
                List(parentA.bs.indices, id: \.self) { idx in
                    NavigationLink(destination: CView(parentA: self.$parentA, parentB: self.$parentA.bs[idx])) {
                        Text(self.parentA.bs[idx].name)
                    }
                }.pullToRefresh(isShowing: self.$refreshing) {
                    API.getBs(forA: self.parentA) { newBObjects in
                        self.parentA.bs = newBObjects
                        self.refreshing = false
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text(parentA.name), displayMode: .inline)
        .onAppear() {
            if(self.parentA.bs.isEmpty) {
                API.getBs(forA: self.parentA) { newBObjects in
                    self.parentA.bs = newBObjects
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CView: View {
    
    @Binding var parentA : A
    @Binding var parentB : B
    
    @State private var refreshing = false
    
    var body: some View {
            VStack {
                if(parentB.cs.isEmpty) {
                    Text("loading")
                } else {
                    List(parentB.cs.indices, id: \.self) { idx in
                        Text(self.parentB.cs[idx].name + self.parentB.cs[idx].description)
                    }.pullToRefresh(isShowing: self.$refreshing) {
                        API.getCs(forB: self.parentB, inA: self.parentA) { newCObjects in
                            self.parentB.cs = newCObjects
                            self.refreshing = false
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text(parentB.name), displayMode: .inline)
            .onAppear() {
                if(self.parentB.cs.isEmpty) {
                    API.getCs(forB: self.parentB, inA: self.parentA) { newCObjects in
                        self.parentB.cs = newCObjects
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}


class API {
    
    static func getAs(complete : @escaping ([A]) -> Void) {
        // normaly download from server
        let aobjects = [A(id: 1, name: "1"), A(id: 2, name: "2"), A(id: 3, name: "3")]
        complete(aobjects)
    }
    
    static func getBs(forA : A, complete: @escaping ([B]) -> Void) {
        // normaly download all bs for a provided A from server
        let bObjects = [B(id: 4, name: "4"), B(id: 5, name: "5")]
        complete(bObjects)
    }
    
    static func getCs(forB : B, inA: A, complete: @escaping ([C]) -> Void) {
        // normaly download all cs for a provided B in parent A from server
        let cObjects = [C(id: 6, name: "name", description: "desc")]
        complete(cObjects)
    }
}

struct A {
    public let id : Int
    public let name : String
    public var bs = [B]()
    
    init(id: Int, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}

struct B {
    public let id : Int
    public let name : String
    public var cs = [C]()
    
    init(id: Int, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}

struct C {
    public let id : Int
    public let name : String
    public let description : String
    
    init(id: Int, name: String, description : String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
    }
}
```

This works so far. The User can navigate from an AView to a BView to a CView. The problem and the error form the headline appears if the user does the following: Start at AView, go to BView, go to CView, go back to BView, go back to AView, refreshing via pull down gesture. In other cases it doesnt happen, eg. Start at AView, go to BView, go to CView, go back to BView, go back to AView, **go to an other BView, go back to AView,** refreshing via pull down gesture, this works. Any idea how to prevent the exception?

Thanks in advance

Edit: Full error message

> Fatal error: Index out of range: file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-1103.2.25.8/swift/stdlib/public/core/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift, line 444
> 2020-07-30 14:16:37.652919+0200 TestForArray[11908:625819] Fatal error: Index out of range: file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-1103.2.25.8/swift/stdlib/public/core/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift, line 444

Comment: does it fail under "normal" conditions (when new data arrives), or does it also fail with fixed refresh data, like in the question